# Apple Push Notification (APN) - when to use sandbox and production?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I like to know when to use sandbox APNS (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com) and when to use production APNS (gateway.push.apple.com) to send push notification.

Currently we are using production APNS for

- app store version, and
- testflight version

of the app and sandbox APNS for the local (debug) version. Is this correct?

The problem is that, although we receive push notification correctly for App Store version, we do not receive push notification for testflight and local versions.

We are using same production certificate for all the versions. Is this correct?

Comment: Production cert can only be used for AppStore & AdHoc Release. For other kinds of builds.. use Sandbox..

Answer (score 5):

SandBox for apps signed with **iOS Development Certificate** (Debug default)

Production for apps signed with **iOS Distribution Certificate** (Release default, including testFlight)

Note that testFlight builds are exactly same with the AppStore builds if you don't have complete separate uploads with different version or build numbers.

Comment: Thank you, how do I know at runtime how the app was signed?

Comment: Why you need to know at run time? You just pass tokens to server and let it decide to send to development versions or production versions.

Comment: Pls let me know if you know how to do it. Why we need it is our own internal logic.

Comment: `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt"` is true on TestFlight and false otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended approach: Send your request first to the production APNS, and when that fails, send it to the sandbox APNS. And always do that, without exception.

The reason: In practice, 99.9% of all your push notifications will be handled correctly by the production APNS. There is the 0.09% that are sent by developers, which will be handled a bit slower (one rejection followed by one success) and the 0.01% that should succeed with the production APNS but for some reason don't (instead of failing once, you try twice and fail twice).

The big advantage is that it *just works*. You don't have to configure your server where to send push notifications, and you don't have to configure the client to tell the server where to send push notifications. You just send the push and it works.

Comment: Where is the source of your recommendation?

Comment: How do you check for failures?

Comment: This sounds like the Apple recommendation for InAppPurchases, however I haven't yet seen anything that recommends this approach for push notifications.  In my implementation the app knows I'm in debug mode and tells the server to register my push notification as a test device.  When the server goes to submit a push it checks to see whether the device was registered as a debug device (for sandbox APNS url) or a release / TestFlight build (for live APNS url)

Comment: I do not think this is good advice - Imagine you plan to send "test test banana" to a specific device ID in sandbox but sandbox was temporarily offline, this test message will then be attempted in production and might be sent to the wrong device - to a live customer.  Admittedly the tokens are probably entirely different, but let's assume the worst and avoid this.  This would be more of a problem if Apple adds a 'broadcast' feature, in this scenario it would be very valid to say send "test test banana" to all users in sandbox to then accidentally be sent to LIVE users.